# Wordpress ajax search also in custom post types

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have a post type called 'accelerate' and in that post type I have a custom field called inspiration (a text field).

I also have an ajax search that displays posts whilst typing.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });
```

and this php function to query:

```
function data_fetch() {

    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
        'post_type' => 'accelerate'
    ) );
    $the_second_query = new WP_Query( array ( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_type' => 'accelerate',
        'meta_key' => 'inspiration',
        'meta_value' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
    ));
    $the_query->posts = array_merge( $the_query->posts, $the_second_query->posts );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
       ...output html
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Expected behaviour is that it searches in the post as well as in the inspiration custom fields, but the latter is not true.

How can I do an ajax search in posts as well as in its custom fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the meta_query argument in your WP_Query like this

```
function data_fetch() {
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        's' => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']), 
        'post_type' => 'accelerate'
    ));
    $the_second_query = new WP_Query(array( 
        'posts_per_page'    => -1, 
        'post_type'     => 'accelerate',
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'       => 'inspiration',
                'value'       => esc_attr($_POST['keyword']),
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
    ));
    $the_query->posts = array_merge($the_query->posts,$the_second_query->posts);
    if($the_query->have_posts()){ ?>
        ...output html
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I finally ended up using the meta_query and the _meta_or_title argument instead of the 's'. That worked